# TextField click changes Switch in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, statefulwidget

As soon as a `TextField` gets focused, an object which stores if it's enabled changes so that the `TextField` gets disabled immediately. This also happens when another `TextField` above gets focused.

The `TextField` is placed inside a StatefulWidget and a `Category` object contains another object called `Goal` which contains a `bool` variable if it's enabled or disabled. This variable is also used to enable or disable the `TextField`.

```
TextField(
  controller: _goalAmountController,
  enabled: widget.category.goal.enabled,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Goal Amount",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
  onChanged: (value) {
    try {
      widget.category.goal.amount = double.parse(value);
    } on Exception {
      //TODO display error message
      print("Invalid Goal-Amount");
    }
  },
),
```

There's also a `switch` below the `TextField` to enable or disable the `Goal` by setting it's `enabled` variable.

```
        SwitchListTile(
          value: widget.category.goal.enabled,
          title: Text("Enable Goal"),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(
              () {
                widget.category.goal.enabled = value;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
```

I found out that it seems as if the click on a `TextField` would replace the `Goal` object with a new one which has `false` as the default value for `enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `FocusNodes` instead :

```
FocusNode textNode = FocusNode();

TextField(
  focusNode: textNode,
  controller: _goalAmountController,
  enabled: widget.category.goal.enabled,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Goal Amount",
  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
),
```

later when you want to disable this textField when the user interact with another widget you can call:

```
textNode.unfocus() ;
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. And I can't call `textNode.unfocus() ;` because I don*t know when the user interacts with another Widget

Comment: you can wrap the whole form inside an `InkWell`, this worked for me when creating registration forms. On its `onTap` method call `textNode.unfocus()`